# How to make Opera to ignore system palette in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, gui, opera

I have black background in Lubuntu and in some GUIs Opera show me black font on black background. For example, in Notes - I can see name of the note only when I select it:

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Try use Opera themes. Disable GTK+ and use something else.

Comment: Where disable GTK+? In Opera?

Comment: You think themes for Opera affect font color in Notes? I tried some of them - seems like it's not working.

Comment: You can change fonts in the settings.

Comment: Type `opera:config` into the address bar and have a look through the Colour and Interface Colour settings in there.

Comment: Tried - seems like there are no settings for this colors :(

Answer (score 0):

In Opera go to big **Opera Tab** on your upper left and click **Appearence** or you can just **shift+F12**

[image]

Click on **theme** of your choice and click **OK**. You can also discover new theme by clicking **Find More Theme** button.

Hope it help.

Comment: No, it's not affect notes name.